# Кнопка в уведомлениях приложения

Tags: android

Создаю уведомление для Activity таким образом

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// Намерение для запуска второй активности
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Second.class);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

// Строим уведомление
Notification builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setTicker("Пришла посылка!")
        .setContentTitle("Играет: " + котенок)
        .setContentText("Это я, почтальон Печкин. Принес для вас посылку")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_play).setContentIntent(pIntent)
        .addAction(R.drawable.icon_stop, "ОК", pendingMyIntent)
        .build();

// убираем уведомление, когда его выбрали
builder.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

notificationManager.notify(0, builder);
```

Сейчас если нажать на кнопку ОК, то открывается вторая активиту. А как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку происходило то, что мне нужно? Например чтобы выполнялся какой-то метод.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать BroadcastReceiver, который будет отлавливать intent. отправлять intent так:

```
Intent maybeReceive = new Intent();  
maybeReceive.setAction(MAYBE_ACTION);
PendingIntent pendingIntentMaybe = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 12345, maybeReceive, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

соответственно ваш код будет такой:

```
 NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
   Intent maybeReceive = new Intent();  
    maybeReceive.setAction(MAYBE_ACTION);
    PendingIntent pendingIntentMaybe = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 12345, maybeReceive, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // Строим уведомление
        Notification builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setTicker("Пришла посылка!")
                .setContentTitle("Играет: " + котенок)
                .setContentText("Это я, почтальон Печкин. Принес для вас посылку")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_play).setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.icon_stop, "ОК", pendingIntentMaybe)
                .build();

        // убираем уведомление, когда его выбрали
        builder.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        notificationManager.notify(0, builder);
```

Comment: Плохо понял что тут произошло :( Тут по нажатию на кнопку в итоге создается новый Intent?

Comment: У меня есть активити Second с методом stop() хотелось чтобы по нажатию на кнопку выполнялся этот метод грубо говоря

Comment: Зарегистрируйте `broadcastreceiver` с нужным вам `intentfilter` в этом `activity` и и в методе `onReceive` выполняйте метод `stop`

Comment: а можно в виде кода показать как это будет?